# Is it possible to display an OpenCV video inside the IPython /JuPyter Notebook?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

When running the examples from the OpenCV video processing python tutorials, they all pop up in a dedicated window. I know that the IPython notebook can display videos from disk and YouTube, so I wonder if there is a way to direct the OpenCV video playback to the Notebook browser and have it play in the output cell instead of a separate window (preferably without saving it to disk and then playing it from there).

Below is the code from the OpenCV tutorial.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/path/to/video') 

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm also looking for this and didn't find any solution yet... I guess its not possible as the kernel stays active as long as the window exists. So if the window was inside the workbook then we couldn't close it, which means the current cell would be running its code, etc...

Comment: check this:https://github.com/bikz05/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/computer-vision/displaying-video-in-ipython-notebook.ipynb

Comment: The link provided by @EzerK can be considered as the solution

Comment: I tried the solution provided by @EzerK. It does display the video in the notebook, but the frame rate is very low so the video looks choppy. I tried streaming from my webcam with python3.5 and opencv3 v3.1.0. Videos from my disk would not play at all.

Comment: Any updates on this? I also want to run it through my notebook.

Comment: @moondra Nope, but I have not been actively pursuing this since my last comment, so you might be able to find something if you look around.

Comment: For reference, [to display video from hard disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook).

Answer (score 10):

To make the display faster use only `IPython.display.display` inside the notebook and JPG format instead of PNG. (Note displaying with `cv2.imshow` natively outside the notebook is much faster, but this is not what the question asks for):

The code below will test all the supported file formats to find the fastest one (extracted from `__doc__` with a regex, not reliable)

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display, HTML
import cv2

# Read one frame from the camera for testing
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, frame = video.read()
video.release()

import re
from timeit import timeit
import math

extensions=re.findall(r"\\\*(\.\w*)", cv2.imread.__doc__)

def test(extension):
    try:
        totalTime=0
        numTry=3
        for _ in range(numTry):
            totalTime+=timeit(lambda: display(Image(data=cv2.imencode(extension, frame)[1])), number=1)
            clear_output(wait=True)
        return totalTime/numTry, extension

    except cv2.error as e: #usually "unsupported file type"
        return (math.inf, extension, e)
for x in sorted(
    [test(extension) for extension in extensions], key=lambda x: x[0]
): print(x)
```

In my case, `.jpeg` is the fastest. Make sure that the browser display also support that extension:

```
Image(data=cv2.imencode(".jpeg", frame)[1].tobytes())
```

Then, to play the video:

```
import cv2
from IPython.display import display, Image

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
display_handle=display(None, display_id=True)
try:
    while True:
        _, frame = video.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) # if your camera reverses your image
        _, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)
        display_handle.update(Image(data=frame.tobytes()))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    video.release()
    display_handle.update(None)
```

`update` is a little faster than `clear_output` + `display` every time; however compare to the rendering it isn't a significant improvement.

Comment: Remark: at the time of testing this is faster than Bokeh. Besides you can do `Image(data=<numpy array>)` as well, although that usage isn't [explicitly documented](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image.__init__)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with Bokeh and probably it is a bit faster.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook
import cv2
import time
output_notebook()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA) # because Bokeh expects a RGBA image
frame=cv2.flip(frame, -1) # because Bokeh flips vertically
width=frame.shape[1]
height=frame.shape[0]
p = figure(x_range=(0,width), y_range=(0,height), output_backend="webgl", width=width, height=height)
myImage = p.image_rgba(image=[frame], x=0, y=0, dw=width, dh=height)
show(p, notebook_handle=True)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    frame=cv2.flip(frame, -1)
    myImage.data_source.data['image']=[frame]
    push_notebook()
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately it is not working for me. I tried with a file from disk, but the video lags significantly and only advances 1 frame every few seconds (I tried both JupyterNotebook and JupyterLab). Is playback as smooth for you as when playing the video in a dedicated player such as VLC?

Comment: Works well! You can interrupt easily from menu.

Comment: Note that recent version of bokeh requires (w, h) array of uint32, while opencv outputs (w, h, 4) array of uint8. So it's necessary to convert between them. (use frame = frame.view(dtype=numpy.uint8).reshape(frame.shape[:2]) for example) Although I still find this method a little slower than use IPython.display with jpeg format (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518369/5267751)), and much slower than cv2.imshow in a separate window.

Answer (score 2):

The video encoded data (if in a format the browser can decode, eg. h264-encoded in ISO mp4 container) can be displayed using an HTML `<video>` tag and `IPython.core.display.HTML()`, this will provide standard playback performance.

The `<video>` can be a link, or have embedded base64'ed data (the latter is what `matplotlib.animation` does, for example), and its data can of course be generated in your notebook, using OpenCV (eg. `VideoWriter`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But it will be slooowwww....

Code with Python 3 and OpenCV 3.3 that reads from webcam (from file, just change cv2.VideoCapture("filename.mp4")):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display, HTML
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64

def arrayShow (imageArray):
    ret, png = cv2.imencode('.png', imageArray)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(png)
    return Image(data=encoded.decode('ascii'))
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    try:
        clear_output(wait=True)
        _, frame = video.read()
        lines, columns, _ =  frame.shape
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(columns/4), int(lines/4))) 
        img = arrayShow(frame)
        display(img)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        video.release()
```

You may need to change IOPub data rate limit.
You can change this in your .jupyter config or just run
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000

The keyboard interrupt doesn't work properly, though.

Comment: In python3 you should change `Image(data=encoded.decode('ascii'))` to `Image(data=png)`

Comment: You need to add `break` in the `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display

import ipywidgets

import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

display_handle=display(None, display_id=True)

image_widget = ipywidgets.Image(format='jpeg')


while True:

    try:
        clear_output(wait=True)
        _, frame = video.read()
        lines, columns, _ =  frame.shape
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(columns/4), int(lines/4))) 
        image_widget.value =cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)[1].tobytes()
        display(image_widget)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        video.release()
        break
```