# How to play google drive video in google colab?

Tags: python

I need to play the video by giving url of google drive video in goolge colab.

'''   '''

Answer (score 1):

See : [how play mp4 video in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377185/how-play-mp4-video-in-google-colab). Copy your Drive file into the running directory of Colab and then play the video.