# Problems with video urls in python

Tags: url, video, ipython

I'm doing this

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video(sample_video_url)
```

sample_video_url is a string and contain a video url.
It works only with this kind of url: https://cvbp.blob.core.windows.net/public/datasets/action_recognition/action_sample.mp4

I have to work with many videos, so I tried to put you_tube urls, or video urls from my computer but it doesn't work.

After *Video(sample_video_url)* I have other lines code, but before I want to understand the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this question [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook) which seems like it is very closely related to your problem.
I think you may be missing some essential formatting here.

**Note: I uploaded the videos to the file browser/list of notebooks before this worked completely on my system**

See:

```
from IPython.display import Video

Video("test.mp4")
```

That particular question that I linked also shows how you can use HTML5 formatting to include video as well:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
    <video alt="test" controls>
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
""")
```

For Youtube videos this works:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
youtube_video = YouTubeVideo('video-url-string-here')
display(youtube_video)
```

There's also the magic cell method:

```
%%HTML
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="path/to/your.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```