# How do I embed a local video into Jupyter Notebook that I can then convert to a PDF?

Tags: pdf, video, jupyter-notebook, latex

Have a local video that I'd like to embed into a jupyter notebook and then convert that jupyter notebook into a PDF but am having difficulties. Have tried solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook) but the video does not display properly in the notebook and the converted pdf just has code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook