# Define the conditional Jupyter cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I have Jupyter Notebook tutorials that I used Matplotlibe and ipywidgets(interact) to display video with NumPy 3D format.

```py
class JupyterDisplay():
 

    def __init__(self, video, median_filter_flag=False, color='gray', imgSizex=5, imgSizey=5, IntSlider_width='500px'):
        
        self.color = color
        self.video = video
        self.imgSizex = imgSizex
        self.imgSizey = imgSizey
        self.median_filter_flag = median_filter_flag

        interact(self.display, frame=widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=self.video.shape[0] - 1, step=1, value=10,
                                                       layout=Layout(width=IntSlider_width),
                                                       readout_format='10', continuous_update=False,
                                                       description='Frame:'))

    def display(self, frame):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(self.imgSizex, self.imgSizey))
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

        if self.median_filter_flag:
            frame_v = median_filter(self.video[int(frame), :, :], 3)
        else:
            frame_v = self.video[int(frame), :, :]

        myplot = ax.imshow(frame_v, cmap=self.color)
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
        plt.colorbar(myplot, cax=cax)

        plt.show()
```

I want to create an HTML version from tutorials with `sphinx make HTML`. But the video is not visualized in the HTML version. What is the best way to display dynamic video in the HTML version?

I can create the mp4 from videos, but in this case, I need to have a conditional Jupyter cell to only run this part of the code when making HTML Sphinx used. Can you inform me how I should define this conditional cell?

Comment: Did you try: from IPython.display import Video
Video("test.mp4") 


From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019477/how-can-i-play-a-local-video-in-my-ipython-notebook

Comment: Thank you! I know we can convert this to HTML but since this converter is too slow, I want to run the converter part only when I want to create HTML. Is there any automatic way that can detect these cells run to make HTML or by python kernel?